# NSData bytes difference and java bytes difference

Tags: android, ios, nsdata, bytecode

I need to send a .jpeg file to the server and I convert the .jpeg to NSData like `imagebytesss =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anotherimg, 0.75);` but in android it sends normal bytes that takes directly from stream but it has difference characters of bytes than iOS(NSData).

Does anyone know, the difference between NSData bytes and Android, or incase how to convert my .jpeg to bytes like java in iOS.

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to send a jpg file to a server then send the file to the server. Why would you convert to some NSData? For what? This has nothing to do with Android if your Android code just sends the bytes of the file. Unclear what you are doing or what you want.

Comment: Actually, Android convert jpg to bytes without any encoding but in iOS when i convert .jpg convert to bytes with NSData it comes different characters not sure if NSData using encoding. is there any way to convert .jpg without encoding in iOS?

Comment: You did not tell why you use NSData to begin with.

Comment: I need to use NSData in iOS to convert .jpg to bytes in order to make post request to the server.

Comment: `Android convert jpg to bytes without any encoding ` ??? Strange wording. Android will just upload the bytes of the file i think you mean.

Comment: `to convert .jpg to bytes` Again a strange wording. The jpg file consists of bytes. So you could just take the bytes of the file. Dont convert to begin with. If you have to place them in a non byte buffer then be carefull. How many bytes is the file? And how many do you receive at server? And does the server know how to handle NSData? What does the server do with the received bytes?

Comment: Server can not handle NSData, that is why when I use proxy to check the difference bytes between iOS and Android, I see that Android use difference bytes with our encoding but mine with NSdata encode it.

Comment: Until now you did not tell if the received NSData bytes is a valid image file. And we are waiting for figures.

Comment: My question was, can I convert .jpg image to bytes without encoding, using or not using NSData?

Comment: Just tell the files sizes. Three figures we wanna hear. And why are you refusing to tell if you got a valid image?

Comment: Yes, I get the valid image and the byte size with NSdata is: 845820.I get the file from image library iPhone.

Comment: I asked for three file sizes. Or two for iOs. original and uploaded. You should long have checked that your self of course. Know what happens.

Comment: When I take image from iPhone and convert it to NSdata It gives the size of bytes. there is not file size before or after.

Comment: The file size nothing to do with my question..

Comment: If you cannot find the original file size.... It has all to do with your problem. Otherwise i would not ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageJPEGRepresentation encodes an image with specified compression quality, but as far as I understood you want to upload the binary image data unchanged.

To achieve this you could create a NSData object with a local URL like so:

```
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
```

Swift 4 example with a local JPG file named 'coffee.jpg' in the main bundle:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "coffee", withExtension:"jpg") {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        //upload it
    }
}
```